# How to match a character in the middle of the string with known but variable size prefix

Tags: regex, cfengine

To be more specific, there is a line (among other lines in a given string):

```
sudo:x:27:foo,bar,baz
         ^---we need to match this character
```

The prefix is known, and can be expressed as `^sudo:x:\d+`

The problem: positive lookbehind assertion must be of a fixed size, otherwise I would use `(?<=sudo:x:\d+)`

The question: how to match that exact colon (and it must be the only matched character)

Playground: http://regex101.com/r/gG9vW6/2

PS: For those who are curious why I need that:

This is just a part of the bigger task, which could be expressed as: add a user to the sudo group if it is not there yet with the following parser limitations (it comes from the software being used, cannot be changed):

- You can only perform *replace* operation, so you need to *match* any character
- It is technically impossible to use the regex `(matches)` and references in the replacement string

**UPDATE**

There **is** a way to use the `(matches)`, so it's not a problem anymore :-)

This is how to refer to the matches in cfengine:

`$(match.N)`

where N is the index of the capturing group.

See: https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.5/manuals-language-concepts-pattern-matching-and-referencing.html

Comment: does your language supports `\K`? If yes, then you could simply use this `^sudo:x:\d+\K:` http://regex101.com/r/pD5sV6/10

Comment: @AvinashRaj see the "UPD" part, but nice idea indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=^sudo:x:\d+:.*$)(.*):
```

You can try this.

Replace with:

```
$(match.1)<your char>
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pD5sV6/9) for equivalent version in PCRE.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/gG9vW6/2 --- sorry, I must have been expressed that more explicitly: it must take into account that it's `sudo` not something else

Comment: @zerkms can you try now

Comment: In your regex you match more than a single character.

Comment: "replace by" --- `\1` is not available, it's a parser limitation

Comment: Found a way to refer to the matches, so now it's trivial, thanks :-)

Comment: @zerkms: Can you tell us how to refer to the matches? Both the question and answer are effectively useless without that information.

Comment: @nhahtdh `$(match.N)` https://docs.cfengine.com/docs/3.5/manuals-language-concepts-pattern-matching-and-referencing.html